# Python Cmd: trying to return a value from a function but told it is being referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, return-value, python-cmd

im making a game with pythons cmd module but I've run into this problem. I have a function that I pass a variable into, the function changes it and returns it. but when I set the function equal to the variable it says that `value` has been referenced before assignment. however it doesn't do this if I don't set the function equal to `value`, but obviously `value` hasn't changed on the global level. I have tried to find a solution but can't thought I'd ask here. any help appreciated.

```
from cmd import Cmd

class stuff(Cmd):
    def do_command(self, args):
        value = command(value)

def command(value):
    value = "new value"
    return value

value = "value"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prompts = stuff()
    prompts.cmdloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it by just putting a golbal variable in the `do_command` function like so:

```
from cmd import Cmd

class stuff(Cmd):
    def do_command(self, args):
        global value
        value = command(value)

def command(value):
    value = "new value"
    return value

value = "value"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prompts = stuff()
    prompts.cmdloop()
```